# JQuery autocomplete validation in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, autocomplete

I'm using the default rails validations, that generate a surrounding red box in the fields with errors.

So, after a post, a code like this:

```
<input id="post_date" name="post[date]" type="text">
```

will became like this:

```
<div class="field_with_errors">
   <input id="post_date" name="post[date]" type="text">
</div>
```

so, with a simple css we can set a red border:

```
.field_with_errors input{border: 1px red}
```

My problem began when I put an autocomplete field in my form. To send the "id" value to server and show the "name" value in the field, I create a hidden field for the id, like this:

```
<p>
  <%= f.label :user %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :user_id%>
  <%= text_field_tag :user %>
</p>
```

Where the "text_field_tag" is my autocomplete:

```
$("input#user").autocomplete({...});
```

And the hidden field will carry the id for a server post.

After this, if this field has an error (like required), Rails does not surround any of this with the magical div element.

Any clue on that ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you would need to use the form-helper in order to get error-highlighting. so you would need to `f.text_field :user` if that's where your validation is on.

Comment: This does not work, because it tries to send the user's name field (the one that is displayed) as id field.

Comment: regardless of wether this works, that's the thing you need do when you wan't rails to highlight it. otherwise you need to add the css classes yourselfs. in this case you need to look at `@user.errors` or `f.error_messages` look at the guides for more detail http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#displaying-validation-errors-in-the-view

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that:

```
<div class="<%= object.errors[:user].present? ? 'field_with_errors' : '' %>">
 Your text_field_tag with autocomplete
</div>
```

Example:

```
<div class="<%= object.errors[:user].present? ? 'field_with_errors' : '' %>">
  <%= text_field_tag nil, default, :id => 'user_email_autocomplete', data: {autocomplete_source: User.order(:email).map { |t| {:label => t.email, :value => t.id} }} %>
</div>
<%= f.hidden_field :user_id %>
```